# Elasticsearch _boost deprecated. Any alternative?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch, mapping

So basically `_boost`, which was a mapping option to give a field a certain boost [is now deprecated](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost-field.html)

The page suggest to use "[function score](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) instead of boost". But function score means:

> The function_score allows you to modify the score of documents that are retrieved by a query

So it's not even an alternative. Function score just modifies the score of the documents at query time.

How i do alter the relevante of **a field** at the **mapping** time?

That option is not valid anymore? Removed and no replacement?

Comment: Boosts "just modify the score of the documents at query time".  They do so using a value stored with the document at index time, just like the [recommendation in the documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost-field.html#function-score-instead-of-boost).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option is no longer valid and there is no direct replacement. The problem is that index time boosting was removed from Lucene 4.0 upon which Elasticsearch runs. Elasticsearch then used it's own implementation which had it's own issues. A good write up on the issues can be found here: http://blog.brusic.com/2014/02/document-boosting-in-elasticsearch.html and the issue deprecating boost at index time here: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/4664

To summarize, it basically was not working in a transparent and understandable way - you could boost one document by 100 and another by 50, hit the same keyword and yet get the same score. So the decision was made to remove it and rely on function score queries, which have the benefit of being much more transparent and predictable in their impact on scoring.

If you feel strongly that function score queries do not meet your needs and use case, I'd open an issue in github and explain your case.

Answer (score 1):

Function score query can be used to boost the whole document. If you want to use field boost, you can do so with a [multi match query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#_literal_fields_literal_and_per_field_boosting) or a [term query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html#query-dsl-term-query).

Comment: But my question is "How i do alter the relevante of a field at the mapping time?". Mapping time, not query time...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your case but I believe you have strong reasons to boost documents at index time. It is always recommended to boost at "Query" as "Index" time boosting will require reindexing the data again if ever your boost criteria changes. Being said that, in my application we have implemented both Index & Query time boosting, we are using

1. Index Time Boosting (document boosting), to boost some documents which we know will always be TOP HIT for our search. e.g searching with word "google" should always put a document containing "google.com" as top hit. We do this using a custom boost field and a custom boosting script to achieve this. Please see this link: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html
2. Query time Boosting (Per field boosting), we are using ES java APIs to execute our queries, we apply field level boosting at query time to each field as its highly flexible & allows us to change the field level boosting without reindexing the whole data set again.

You can have a look at this, it might be helpful for you: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#_field_value_factor

I have described my complete use case here, hopefully you will find it helpful.